# Is modiagram still functional?

Tags: modiagram

I have been trying to get the package modiagram to work. Unfortunately, every time I try to compile my tex code, I get an error. I've looked around and there does not seem to be much on the package and hasn't been updated for over a year.

I've created a new document and copied the readme examples and none of them have worked.

Thank you

Here is the document

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.7cm, outer=2.7cm, top=2cm,  bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=1.2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{modiagram}


\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{equation} #1 \end{equation}}
\newcommand{\com}[2]{[\hat{#1},\hat{#2}]}
\newcommand{\dhat}[2]{\hat{#1}\hat{#2}}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{me \\ Lab Section 02}
\date{September 18th, 2020}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    
    blah blah this isn't published yet

\end{abstract}
\blfootnote{people}

\newpage

\section*{Introduction}

not published


\section*{Experimental Details}

Infrared absorption data of HCl gas was collected using an FTIR spectrometer. 

\section*{Results and Analysis}

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{Aug14HClpks_Trans.png}
    \caption{Absroption Spectrum of HCl gas}
    \label{HClspectrum}
 \end{figure}

\section*{Summary and Conclusion}

\begin{modiagram}
    \atom{left}{1s, 2s, 2p}
\end{modiagram}

\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/me/Documents/rest of path"  "/Users/william/Documents/Stony Brook/Fall 2020/CHE357/HCl - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/WilliamLaderer_HCl.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/me/Documents/rest of path  - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/me_HCl.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/breqn.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/flexisym.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/physics/physics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esdiff/esdiff.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mhchem/mhchem.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/modiagram/modiagram.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex))) (/Users/me/Documents/Stony Brook/Fall 2020/CHE357/HCl - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/WilliamLaderer_HCl.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
> \l__modiagram_atom_two_s_dim=56.9055pt.
<recently read> }
                 
l.84    \atom{left}{1s, 2s, 2p}
                             
[2 </Users/me/Documents/rest of path - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/Aug14HClpks_Trans.png (PNG copy)>] [3] (/Users/me/Documents/rest of path  Document/me_HCl.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb>
Output written on "/Users/william/Documents/Stony Brook/Fall 2020/CHE357/HCl - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/WilliamLaderer_HCl.pdf" (3 pages, 141868 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/me/Documents/path - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/me_HCl.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on "/Users/me/Documents/path - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/me_HCl.log".
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'WilliamLaderer_HCl.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to '/Users/me/Documents/path - Rotovibrational/HCl Document/me_HCl.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Comment: I just tested that `modigram` (https://ctan.org/pkg/modiagram) works. Perhaps you can post (by editing the question) a full example you used and the error message you got.

Comment: there is a `\dim_show:N \l__modiagram_atom_two_s_dim` in the code, which probably has been forgetten from some debugging. Add an issue at the github issue tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What information is necessary to do that?

Comment: Only your example. But shorten it, all the other packages are not needed to reproduce the error. And compile only with pdflatex, latexmk is not involved.(But the other will also understand if you simply mention dim_show. It is really an obvious error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modiagram will not compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566859/modiagram-will-not-compile) (I chose a more recent thread because the linked one has a better MWE than this one and the issue is the same).