# Modiagram will not compile

Tags: modiagram

I am trying to work with the modiagram package, and it doesn't work. It isn't even running the code that I copied directly from the package documentation. This is the code that I copied:

```
\begin{modiagram}
 \atom{left}{
    1s = {   0; pair} ,
    2s = {   1; pair} ,
    2p = {1.5; up, down }
 }
\end{modiagram}
```

It results in the following error:

```
> \l__modiagram_atom_two_s_dim=28.45274pt.
<recently read> }
```

Comment: show a complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: I just remembered, that has been reported already. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562661/2388 and https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/modiagram/issues/4/issue-with-dim_show-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, a `\dim_show:N` instruction found its way in the `.sty` file.

Until the package is updated one can fix the issue by injecting code that makes LaTeX to ignore the wrong tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nx \__modiagram_two_s:
 {
  \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
  \exp_not:o { \__modiagram_two_s: }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{modiagram}
 \atom{left}{
    1s = {   0; pair} ,
    2s = {   1; pair} ,
    2p = {1.5; up, down }
 }
\end{modiagram}

\end{document}
```

Remove the code from `\ExplSyntaxOn` up to `\ExplSyntaxOff` (both included) when the package is updated to fix the bug.

This holds for `modiagram 2019/10/31 v0.3`.